# undefined reference to `__guia1_ej14_MOD_crea' when compiling Fortran code

Tags: fortran, geany

I'm trying to write a program that uses a module with functions and subroutines, but geany tells me this when I try to build:

```
gfortran -Wall -o "ej15" "ej15.f90" (en el directorio: C:\Users\Pedro\proyectos\Guia 1)
C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNhadr.o:ej15.f90:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `__guia1_ej14_MOD_crea'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Ha fallado la compilación.
```

the program is:

```
 program Guia1_ej15

 use Guia1_ej14

 implicit none

 integer n
 real(8), allocatable:: a(:,:)

 print*, 'Ingrese dimension de matriz'
 read*, n
 print*,' '

 allocate (a(n,n))

 call crea(a,n)

 end program
```

And the module is:

```
 module Guia1_ej14

 contains

 subroutine crea(b,m)
 implicit none

 integer i,j,m
 real(8),allocatable:: b(:,:)

 do i=1,m
    do j=1,m
     read*, b(i,j)
    end do
 end do

 end subroutine crea

 end module Guia1_ej14
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question title was very bad, I changed it to something more specific. You should give us more information. Is the module in a different file? How do you compile it? How did you setup the project/compilation in Geany? We need as much information as possible. Please note that we already have many questions and answers about the `undefined reference` error.

Comment: It appears that  `Guia1_ej14` is in a different file.  You likely have a `guia_ej14.o` file.  Add this to your command line: `gfortran -Wall -o "ej15" "ej15.f90" guia_ej14.o`.  Don't know how to do this with geany.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i'm new at this. Sorry if my english is not good, i'm from argentina.
Yes, I have two diferent files, one with the module and  the other has the program. both of them are in the same proyect folder

Comment: Pedro, your English is fine.  The problem is you need to tell geany to include the object file with the routine in the linking of the program.  If the file name is `ej14.f90`, then compile this file first and then link in `ej14.o`.

Comment: I think I got it, but I don't know how to link that `ej14.o`  file

Comment: I suggest to first learn to use the compiler from the command line and only then to move to building from a graphical environment. You can do the commands evets listen in your command prompt (shell). They should work. You can of course still ask here how to do it in Geany. However, I cannot help you with that, I do not use Geany.